# convertir contenido de archivos a array

Tags: php, array, csv, php5

Estoy tengo problemas cuando convierto un archivo csv a array. Veran, he creado una función que me hace esa conversion y me returna el array. El proceso lo hace relativamente "bien" y me genera el array pero fijense como es el array resultante:

1. Mostrare la función primero:

   ```
     function convertions($file, $delimt, $encl, $a) { 

              if(!file_exists($file)){ 
                 return false; 
                               }


               $file_lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);


              if($file_lines === array()){
              return NULL;
                         }


                                   if($a === true) {

                 $file_row = array_shift($file_lines);
                 $headers = array_map('trim', str_getcsv($file_row, $delimt, $encl));
                         }

                   $array_result = NULL; 


                     foreach ($file_lines as $row) {

                      if(trim($row) === '')
                                 continue; 


                              $fields_arr = array_map('trim', str_getcsv($row, $delimt, $encl));


                     if($a === true) { 
                             $array_result[] = array_combine ($headers, $fields_arr); 

                                     }

                                else {
                                $array_result[] = $fields_arr; 
                                  }
                                }

                             return $array_result; 
                                 }
                       $new_array = array();
                       $new_array = convertions('file.csv',',','"',true);
                       print_r($new_array);
   ```
2. Colocare aqui el contenido de mi archivo "file.csv":

   ```
      code,name,type,years,versions,rivals,Cost,started,Till
      ookh6547,JAVA,language,20,19874654,C#,0,09/12/1990,present
      25aookh6547,C#,language,30,963542432,JAVA,0,10/10/1989,present
      9ddc3552,PHP,language,25,4543664,python,0,13/5/1994,present
   ```

foto del archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Este es el resultado cuando imprimo el array:

   ```
     Array ( [0] => Array ( [��code] => ookh6547 [name] => JAVA [type] => language [years] => 20 [versions] => 19874654 [rivals] => C# [Cost] => 0 [started] => 09/12/1990 [till] => present ) [1] => Array ( [��code] => 25aookh6547 [name] => c# [type] => language [years] => 30 [versions] => 963542432 [rivals] => JAVA [Cost] => 0 [started] => 10/10/1989 [Till] => present ) [2] => Array ( [��code] => 9ddc3552 [name] => PHP [type] => language [years] => 25 [versions] => 4543664 [rivals] => python [Cost] => 0 [started] => 13/5/1994 [Till] => present ) )
   ```

Cuando intento hacer esto por ejemplo:

```
    echo $new_array[0]['type'];
```

me muestra este error:

```
      Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\xampp\htdocs\ArraysMult\proof.php on line 88
```

No entiendo qué problema tiene con las cabeceras, es como si no las reconociera, o no se. Por ejemplo, tambien hacice otra función(llamemosle fun2) e introduci como parametro este array generado por la función convertions(), y además le pase como segundo parametro una variable con el nombre de una de las cabeceras, ejemplo $cabecera = "type"; fun2(array1, $cabecera); e hice que la función buscara dentro del array a ver si una de las keys tenia el mismo nombre, y debia retornarme "SI" o "NO", dependiendo de lo que encontrar. Pues siempre me arroja que "NO", y esta mal porque dentro del arreglo si esta esa key (type). 
No entiendo qué sucede con estos archivos csv.

Lo que deberia quedarme es algo como esto:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => ookh6547 [name] => JAVA [type] => language [years] => 20 [versions] => 19874654 [rivals] => C# [Cost] => 0 [started] => 09/12/1990 [Till] => present ) [1] => Array ( [code] => 25aookh6547 [name] => C# [type] => language [years] => 30 [versions] => 963542432 [rivals] => JAVA [Cost] => 0 [started] => 10/10/1989 [Till] => present ) [2] => Array ( [code] => 9ddc3552 [name] => PHP [type] => language [years] => 25 [versions] => 4543664 [rivals] => python [Cost] => 0 [started] => 13/5/1994 [Till] => present ) )
```

Existe alguna forma de solucionar este problema?
Existe en PHP alguna forma de "formatear" el archivo csv, o en su defecto, formatear los datos que se extraigan de ese archivo antes de hacer la conversión a array? Ese problema me ha tenido trabado todo el dia.

Espero puedan brindarme alguna sugerencia o ejemplos que me sirvan para solucionar ese problema.

Comment: En preferencias de Sublime agrega: `"show_encoding": true,` y dinos la codificación de tu archivo que te indica a la derecha de la barra de estado.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de hacer una función, pruébala:

```
function parseCsv( string $csvFile, bool $stripUnicode = false ) {
    if(pathinfo($csvFile, 4)=='csv'){
        $pattern = $stripUnicode ? "/(^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$)|\p{So}/u" : "/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/";
        $csvFile = array_map(function($e) use ($stripUnicode, $pattern){
            static $c = 0; 
            static $headers = [];
            $s = $c == 0 ? 'headers' : 'record';
            $$s = preg_replace($pattern, '', explode(',', $e));
            $c++;
            return isset($record) ? @array_combine($headers, $record) : false;
        }, file($csvFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
        return array_values(array_filter($csvFile));
    } else { return false; }
}
```

Solo debes indicar en el primer parametro donde se encuentra el archivo CSV. El segundo parametro es para remover esos simbolos y debe estar en `true` para ello. Usualmente la primera fila de los CSV son cabeceras. Solo funciona con CSV simples como el que presentas.

PD: Debes almacenar el array en una variable. Ej: `$array = parseCsv('../file.csv', true);`

Comment: siento decir que no me sirvió. me sigue mostrando el resultado con estos simbolos �� y me sigue mostrando este error: Undefined index: type. He probado diferentes maneras, no entiendo por qué sucede esto.

Comment: Que extraño, a mi me ha funcionado correctamente con varios archivos. Con que versión de PHP estas trabajando?.

Comment: tengo la versión 7.0.27. no entiendo qué pasa con ese archivo.

Comment: Bueno, habría que buscar que es lo que causan esos símbolos y solucionar el problema de raíz, pero mientras tanto actualizo mi respuesta modificando la función y agregando un parámetro extra para intentar remover esos símbolos. El parámetro debe estar en `true`.

Comment: amigo la función devuelve solo "Array()"; Esta completamente vacía.

Comment: al array resultando he aplicado json_encode() y cuando imprimo el resultado me salen todos los datos con este codigo: "\u0000", por ejemplo para la key "name" me sale algo como: "n\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e"...qué puede ser eso? Lei que \u0000 son caracteres Unicode

Comment: Habría alguna manera de que puedas hacerme llegar ese archivo para analizarlo?. Subirlo en algún sitio o enviarlo a mi correo.

Comment: mmm dejame ver como podria subirlo a algun sitio. Pero fijate, he creado un pequeño script el cual utiliza str_replace, y le va quitando esos caracteres a cada dato de la prima fila del array, o sea en la parte donde estan los titulos.

Comment: el problema es que, no se cómo unirlo todo después en un nuevo array asociativo. Crees que podrias ayudarme con eso?

Comment: el archivo php debe tener un formato utf-8 sin bom para que funcione. y te recomiendo que el archivo csv tambien..